# Android: register keyboard action?

Tags: android

Is there an equivalent of Java's registerKeyboardAction, that allows the handling of a key  event regardless of where it occurs?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)` to handle key events:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    switch (keyCode) {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_Y:
            // do something
            break;
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_N:
            // do something
            break;
    }

    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

This listens for key events only on the Activity where it is defined. If you need to handle key events in every section of your app, you'll need to define onKeyDown on every Activity.